# How do I dynamically set a mongodb field name for a nested document based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to insert data into a Mongodb document for a game coded with Meteor based on what round it is.

I want the final result to be something like this:

```
{
"room" : "TEST",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-05T22:04:47.931Z"),
"started" : true,
"round" : 2,
"players" : [
    {
        "userId" : "ASDF",
        "playerName" : "Ed"
    },
    {
        "userId" : "ZXCV",
        "playerName" : "Joe"
    }
],
"answers" : {
    "1": [
    {
        "userId" : "ASDF",
        "answer" : "asdf"
    },
    {
        "userId" : "ZXCV",
        "answer" : "adfafa"
    }],
    "2": [
    {
        "userId" : "ASDF",
        "answer" : "hello"
    },
    {
        "userId" : "ZXCV",
        "answer" : "hi"
    }]
  }
}
```

The javascript below is for a Meteor package that provides findAndModify functionality.  That's why the syntax is slightly different from standard MongoDB but it basically it parses the arguments and sends a proper query to the Mongo backend so the end result is the same as standard.  The part I'm trying to work out is the $addToSet argument..

```
        result = Rooms.findAndModify({
            query: {
                players: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        userId: userId
                    }
                }
            },
            update: {
                $addToSet: {
                    answers: {
                        round: { // Where round is substituted with "1", "2" etc
                            userId: userId,
                            answer: answer
                        }
                    }
                },
                $inc: {
                        count: 1
                    }
            },
            new: true
        });
```

I found other questions where people basically created a placeholder variable and added the value to it which works out to be something like this:

```
var q = {};
q[round] = round;

update: { $addToSet: q }
```

However that works just for a key value pair.  I think I need to get something like:

```
update: {
        $addToSet: 
        answers: {
            round: { // Where round is dynamically substituted with "1", "2" etc
                userId: userId,
                answer: answer
            }
        }
}
```

Dynamically like below:

```
update: {
        $addToSet: 
        answers: {
            "1": {
                userId: userId,
                answer: answer
            }
        }
}
```

I'm guessing I have to build a JSON object with the nested chunk I want to insert but I have no idea on how to do that?  The nested structure is really confusing me.

**UPDATE:**

In addition to fuzzybabybunny's answer below, I was reading this document http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html which was mentioned in another post and came up with this which has the same effect.  Just another way of looking at the same thing.

```
    var r = {}
    var t = {}
    t.userId = userId;
    t.answer = answer;
    r[round] = t;

    $addToSet: r
```

Comment: You mean like *`round`* can be either `firstLeg` or `lastEncounter`, for example?

Comment: round is just like round 1 of questions in the game.  so I would want something like answers: { 1: {  .....

Comment: Please update your question with the ***actual*** document you would like to have

Comment: The first code block is what I want.  I manually typed it of course so if there's any structural problems that's my fault but I think it shows what I want to get.  See how instead of the field name "round" I have the dynamically assigned number?

Comment: What are you using `$elemMatch` for?

Comment: That's just required for the query to find the room that player is currently in.  So for example locating the user "Ed" I would $elemMatch on userId: "ASDF".  Don't worry about that.

Comment: You can actually seize that to prompt it at the inserted subdocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the entire argument for `findAndModify` programmatically:

```
// I'm assuming round, userId, and answer are defined somewhere already
// Create a function that returns an object with a custom keyname and value

var createObject = function(keyName, value){
  // I have this typeof check because key names cannot be an integer
  if(typeof keyName !== "string"){
    console.log("ERROR! keyName needs to be a string.");
  } else {
    var obj = {};
    obj[keyName] = value;
    return obj;
  }
};

var round = "3";

var userAndAnswer = {
  userId: "SDFSD",
  answer: "hello"
};

var findAndModifyArgument = {
  query: {
    players: {
      $elemMatch: {
        userId: userId
      }
    }
  },
  update: {
    $addToSet: {
      answers: createObject(round, userAndAnswer)
    },
    $inc: {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  new: true
};

// findAndModify is a function that takes a single object as an argument, 
// and that's what we created above
result = Rooms.findAndModify(findAndModifyArgument);
```

Comment: I need to have the "round" field name substituted with a number to get it to look like: $addToSet: { "answers": { "1": { userId: "ASDF" ....

Comment: I see how I had some confusing code in my question that probably mislead you.  Hopefully the edits clear things up.

Comment: Well, let me first ask you why you're structuring your data like this. Why do you want to have a unique key name (1, 2, 3, etc)?

Comment: The game has several rounds of questions and players anwer them.  The reason why I'm structuring it this way is because it should make it easier for me to update the UI by embedding that little bit of information in the structure instead of having a separate "round" field and needing to do additional queries to aggregate and move data around.

Comment: Hmm, the structure is different from what I wanted in the first code block.  However, I see what you did there.  If I remove the answers: part and just do $addToSet: createObject I can get all the answers for the round in an array under the numbered field like I want.  Good enough for my purposes.  Thank you for your help!